# Validation error xsd schema with nested complex types

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

The error that occur during validation is:

```
The element 'Details' in namespace 
'<-namespace->' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 
'PersonAddress' in namespace '<-namespace->'.
```

The schema is as follows (large parts removed, for readability):

```
<xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:all>            
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Details" type="PersonDetails" />
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="PersonDetails">
    <xs:all>        
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="PersonAddress" type="PersonAddress" />
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="PersonAddress">
    <xs:all>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Street" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="ZipCode" type="xs:int" />         
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

When i serialize to the XML using the Schema and my DTO:s I map PersonAddress to either null or a object that reflects 'PersonAddress'

I except my final xml to turn out like:

```
</PersonDetails>
     <PersonAddress xsi:nil="true" />
</PersonDetails>
```

Instead I get an error during validation against the xsd schema as explained first in this post.

---

It works fine when i set minOccurs to zero on the PersonAddress in the PersonDetails:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="PersonAddress" type="PersonAddress" />
```

But then the problem is that when i set the mapped object to 'null' the element does not displays at all. It does not exist.

Anything I missed in the xsd schema?

Comment: Your question looks wrong or incomplete - your error message refers to the `Details` element, but your schema and XML do not show any `Details` element. Should that be a `PersonDetails` element?

Comment: @MattJones The Details element is the Name of the xs:element in Person. Details is the type of PersonDetails

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I had failed to parse that bit in my mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I made a mistake in the DTO.

Now it is up and working with this change:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public PersonAddress PersonAddress { get; set; }
```

Forgot to add the IsNullable tag to the DTO property.

Note to self, check for mindfucks before posting to Stack Overflow..